# Are meta sequences and quantifiers available in CSS selectors?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, node-html-parser

I am expecting that below code will capture all element that have `style` attributes begins with
`background: url(:` or `"background-image: url(`.

```js
import type { HTMLElement } from "node-html-parser";

const rootHTML_Element: HTMLElement = /* ... */;

for (
  const variadicElement of
      this.rootHTML_Element.querySelectorAll("[style*=\"background: url(\"]").
          concat(this.rootHTML_Element.querySelectorAll("[style*=\"background-image: url(\"]"))
) {
  // ...
}
```

(I am using the `node-html-parser` (it means, for Node.js), but I suppose that `querySelectorAll` in Browser JavaScript has same behavior).

Above code works in exact match case, but for example, if to there no space between `background:` and `url`, it will not work.
To solve this problem, the meta sequences and quantifiers are required.
If it was normal regular expression, the solution was :

```
style="background(?:-image)?:\s*url\(
```

How to get same effect for CSS selectors?

Comment: _"How to get same effect for CSS selectors?"_ - that's not possible. You're using the attribute selector there, so you are limited to the "patterns" it provides, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#syntax There is no way to use your own regex instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [CBro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) regex is not an option. You could do something like this (you need to include white space etc. in your selectors)

*Note! the "i" at the end makes the selector case-insensitive*

```css
:is( 
  /* note the white space must match */
  [style*="background-image: url(" i], 
  [style*="background-image:url(" i], 
  [style*="background: url(" i], 
  [style*="background:url(" i]) {
  outline: 2px solid;
}

div {
  margin: .25rem;
  padding: .25rem;
}

div::after {
  content: ': <div style="' attr(style) '">';
}
```

```html
<div style="color: green; background: url(...)">Should Match</div>
<div style="color: green; background:url(...)">Should Match</div>

<div style="color: darkred; background: tomato">Shouldn't Match</div>

<div style="color: green; BACKGROUND-image: url(...) ">Should Match</div>
<div style="color: green; background-image:url(...) ">Should Match</div>
```